# Open fancybox with url of page in address bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox

I have stucked somewhere please have a look and get back to me if you have some idea on that:

I want to open a page in fancybox and url of page which is opened in fancybox should display in address bar. I dont want to display url with http://abc.com#divid it should be a proper url without #divid.

It should be something like that :
http://exanple.com/title1

here is my html code:

```
<a id="example1" href="general.php">Recent Trip to New York</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("a#example1").fancybox();
```

---

Is there any way I can implement the things like I have mentioned..

Comment: The whole idea behing such a gallery is to NOT change the URI. Why would you want that?

Comment: I am making a website something like for his portfolio and he wants some thing like that: http://www.behance.net/ here you will see a when you click on any of the image a different URL is about to generate , I need something like that can you please help?

Comment: @Marcel I guess the OP want friendly URLs that can point to fancybox directly without using fragment identifiers (hash)

Comment: @sudhanshu The link you provided to uses normal links on the index page, no JS powered gallery.

Comment: @JFk yes you are right paul , I need a friendly URL for all images popup...

Answer (score 1):

URL in the browser can be manipulated with HTML5 history, but in this case it would not be advised as the user is simply viewing another page via an iframe, and they remain on the parent page.

[Mozilla Developers: Manipulating The Browser History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)